# Java Math Formula Loops

Tags: java, loops, math, formulas

how do you add formula n! = 1 * 2 * 3 * i  in java that it will be in a loop.  An example is if the user inputs 5 the output will be 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120. If you input 4 the output will be 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
public int formulaMethod(int n) {
 int result = 1;
 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  result *= i;
 }
 return result;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to solve this problem:

```
public static int factorial(int n) 
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        else
        {
            return (n * factorial(n-1));
        } 

  }
```